# WebLogic-Data source connectivity issue

Tags: java, weblogic

First of all thanks for giving opportunity to share or ask.
Here is my query

1. In our environment we have several physical machines, each machine got several managed servers each.
2. Now the issue is:
   One of the managed server in is not able to connect to the data source. But when i am testing the data source on that server it was successful. Still its not initiating any connections.

Here is the error

> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18'
>
> for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <>
>   <> <1465467366887>  <[ServletContext@1271613633[app:HEXWAR
>   module:HEXWAR.war path:/HEXWAR spec-version:2.5]] Problem occurred
>   while serving the error page.
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed

Please find above and assist.

Thanks all in advance
Manoj

Comment: how do you test it? What is the main difference between your test and what you have defined in your Weblogic instance?

Comment: In the console done the test data source on the particular server.

Comment: test was successful and we are able to see in the logs either, but connections are not establishing with the data source.

Comment: and we modified Inactive connections timeout=0, previously its was 600

Comment: can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: sure...can i have your  mail id please? its not incorporating the whole stack trace here.

Comment: maybe you can simply hide or blur critical parts of your stack trace and put it here

Comment: i am not able to send here, any other source to send the stack trace?

Comment: why not? what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Hi Nicolas,the whole stack trace was not being able to copied here...

Comment: Hi Nicolas, posted the stack trace can u please suggest?

Comment: where is it? I can't see it in your question

Comment: Hi, here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747169/weblogic-datasource-connectivity-issue

Comment: Hi Nicolas, we tried a lot on the above issue still persisting the same problem. Kindly help me on this.Here is the stack trace please find.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747169/weblogic-datasource-connectivity-issue