# WebLogic datasource connectivity issue

Tags: java, weblogic

Please find the stack trace for the above mentioned error.
[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1465467366887>  <[ServletContext@1271613633[app:HEXWAR module:HEXWAR.war path:/HEXWAR spec-version:2.5]] Problem occurred while serving the error page.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
atorg.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
atorg.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
atorg.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
atorg.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:527)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ForwardAction.run(ForwardAction.java:22)
atweblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:149)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServletContext.java:2344)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2186)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:170)
atcom.hex.portal.interceptor.dao.IPTrackingDao.auditDetails(IPTrackingDao.java:91)
atcom.hex.portal.interceptor.service.IPTrackingService.auditDetails(IPTrackingService.java:102)
atcom.hex.portal.interceptor.contoller.IPTrackingInterceptor.preHandle(IPTrackingInterceptor.java:103)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:130)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
atorg.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
atorg.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
atorg.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
atorg.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:527)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ForwardAction.run(ForwardAction.java:22)
atweblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:149)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServletContext.java:2344)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2186)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1157)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOROLLBACK(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:68)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doRollback(T4CConnection.java:694)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3943)
atoracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.rollback(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:145)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.XAConnection.rollback(XAConnection.java:878)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.rollback(JTAConnection.java:403)
atorg.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:183)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:162)
atcom.hex.portal.interceptor.dao.IPTrackingDao.auditDetails(IPTrackingDao.java:91)
atcom.hex.portal.interceptor.service.IPTrackingService.auditDetails(IPTrackingService.java:102)
atcom.hex.portal.interceptor.contoller.IPTrackingInterceptor.preHandle(IPTrackingInterceptor.java:103)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:130)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
atorg.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
atorg.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
atorg.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
atorg.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
atorg.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:527)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ForwardAction.run(ForwardAction.java:22)   
atweblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:149)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServletContext.java:2344)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2186)
atweblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>
```

Comment: <Error> <HTTP> <xxx.com> <server_name><[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1465467366887> <BEA-101107> <[ServletContext@1271613633[app:HEXWAR module:HEXWAR.war path:/HEXWAR spec-version:2.5]] Problem occurred while serving the error page.

Comment: Obviously your problem is in com.hex.portal.interceptor.dao.IPTrackingDao.auditDetails, please show us the content of this method

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for the quick reply.Where can i find this method as specified.

Comment: IPTrackingDao is not your class?

Comment: hi,                             com.hex.portal.interceptor.bean.IPTrackingBean.data" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fc7dc624000 nid=0xe755 waiting on condition [0x00007fc80e00e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c2fbc560> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)

Comment: I need the source code of this class